# Copying data from multiple workbook to one masterfile: data not entered in the same row

Tags: excel, vba

i have a code to copy from multiple workbooks to one masterfile. but the problem here is that, there are possibilities that the datafile will contain an empty row. So everytime a new data is added, instead of being in a same row, it will moved up to fill the all the blank column. Sorry If my words are not clear, english isnt my first language. I attached the example here

Expected Result

```
A     B      C      D       E
bb   1234    cc     
ff   3242    ff     
fjn  7643    jk    fjnnD  fjnnE
gwd  9754    jk    gjwdD  gjwdE
```

Result that I get

```
A     B      C      D       E
bb   1234    cc     fjnnD  fjnnE
ff   3242    ff     gjwdD  gjwdE
fjn  7643    jk    
gwd  9754    jk
```

Here is my code

```
Sub UploadData()

Dim SummWb As Workbook
Dim SceWb As Workbook

'Get folder containing files
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    On Error GoTo Error_handler
    myFolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
    'Err.Clear
    'On Error GoTo 0
End With

If Right(myFolderName, 1) <> "\" Then myFolderName = myFolderName & "\"
    'Settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    oldStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Set SummWb = ActiveWorkbook
    'Get source files and append to output file
    mySceFileName = Dir(myFolderName & "*.*")

        Do While mySceFileName <> "" 'Stop once all files found
            Application.StatusBar = "Processing: " & mySceFileName
            Set SceWb = Workbooks.Open(myFolderName & mySceFileName) 'Open file found
                With SummWb.Sheets("Master List")
                                     Dim maxLastRow As Long
             Dim columnsToAppendTo As Variant
             columnsToAppendTo = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "F")
             Dim index As Long

            For index = LBound(columnsToAppendTo) To UBound(columnsToAppendTo)
            maxLastRow = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, columnsToAppendTo(index)).End(xlUp).Row, maxLastRow)
            Next index

                .Cells(maxLastRow + 1, "A").Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B3").Value
                .Cells(maxLastRow + 1, "C").Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B4").Value
                .Cells(maxLastRow + 1, "D").Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B5").Value
                .Cells(maxLastRow + 1, "E").Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B6").Value
                .Cells(maxLastRow + 1, "I").Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C9").Value
                .Cells(maxLastRow + 1, "J").Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D9").Value
                .Cells(maxLastRow + 1, "K").Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C10").Value
                .Cells(maxLastRow + 1, "L").Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D10").Value
                .Cells(maxLastRow + 1, "M").Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C11").Value
                .Cells(maxLastRow + 1, "N").Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D11").Value
                .Cells(maxLastRow + 1, "F").Value = SummWb.Sheets("Upload Survey").Range("C8").Value
                End With
            SceWb.Close (False) 'Close Workbook
            mySceFileName = Dir

        Loop
MsgBox ("Upload complete.")
'Settings and save output file
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = oldStatusBar
SummWb.Activate
SummWb.Save 'save automaticallly
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
Error_handler:
MsgBox ("You cancelled the action.")

End Sub
```

I am guessing the problem is with the End(xlUp) statement. Any kind of help is much appreciated.

edit (deleted portion of the code)

```
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B3").Valu
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B4").Value
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B5").Value
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B6").Value
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C9").Value
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D9").Value
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C10").Value
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D10").Value
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C11").Value
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D11").Value
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SummWb.Sheets("Upload Survey").Range("C8").Value
```

Comment: You only need to use End(xlUp) once, and then all other values should go on that same row: don't run it separately in each column.  You need to pick a column which will have no blanks though.

Comment: meaning, if i specified column A to use the end(xlUp), then i need to delete it from other column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use `End(xlUp)` once, and then all other values should go on that same row: don't run it separately in each column. You need to pick a column which will have no blanks though.

E.g: using ColA

```
With SummWb.Sheets("Master List").Cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(1,0).Entirerow
    .cells(1).value = 'whatever
    .cells(2).value = 'other value
    'etc etc
end with
```

Comment: Hi, i used numbers and it move all my data. So instead of numbers, can I use the alphabet?

Comment: Hi tim, thank you so much!! it works. thank you for input I learn new things today

Answer (score 0):

Untested. There may be a better way to do this, but after this line:

```
With SummWb.Sheets("Master List")
```

Put

```
Dim maxLastRow as long
Dim columnsToAppendTo as variant
columnsToAppendTo = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "F")

Dim index as long

For index = lbound(columnsToAppendTo) to ubound(columnsToAppendTo)

maxLastRow = application.max(.cells(.Rows.Count,  columnsToAppendTo(index)).End(xlUp).row, maxLastRow)

Next index
```

Then re-write the section of your code where you actually write to the master file, as such:

```
.Cells(maxLastRow + 1, "A").Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B3").Value ' Use offset instead of +1 if you need to '
```

And so forth.

The main difference is you work out the last row across all columns first/in advance, then use that particular last row value for each column.

Comment: Hi, it has compile error that said expected, "List separator or ).  for line columnToAppendTo

Comment: Sorry, forgot to close double quotes. And now? Does it work?

Comment: Oh wait. I'll try it first

Comment: Hi, i got compile error for line maxLastRow, particularly the .Rows part.

Comment: I've changed the line to put the code after (it needed to be within the `With` block). Any luck now? I do not have access to a desktop to test at the moment, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, the code can be run, but, there no data being copied, the master list is empty. I'll update the code in my question for you to see.